# Identifing object clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, blackberry-playbook

I'm developing an ActionScript 3 for Blackberry Playbook. I'm very very new on ActionScript 3 development.

I have this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    [SWF(width="1024", height="600", backgroundColor="#cccccc", frameRate="30")]
    public class Transition extends Sprite
    {
        private var imageBack:Loader;
        private var imageFront:Loader;

        public function Transition()
        {
            super();
            createGUI();

            imageBack.load(new URLRequest("assets/images/back.png"));
            imageFront.load(new URLRequest("assets/images/front.png"));

        }

        private function createGUI():void {
            imageBack = new Loader();
            imageBack.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedEvent);
            imageBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onImageClicked);

            imageFront = new Loader();
            imageFront.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedEvent);
            imageFront.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onImageClicked);
        }

        private function onLoadedEvent(event:Event):void {
            // Blah, Blah, Blah...
        }

        private function onImageClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var currentTarget:Loader = Loader(event.currentTarget);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to identify which image has been clicked on `onImageClicked` function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify a [`name`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name) for each of Loaders and check it (or check it without specifying - they'll have different names by default):

```
switch((event.currentTarget as Loader).name){
    case imageBack.name:
    trace('imageBack here');
    break;

    case imageFront.name:
    trace('imageFront here');
    break;
}
```